# Searching File2 with 3 columns from File 1 with awk

Tags: awk, paste

Does anyone know how to print "Not Found" if there is no match, such that the print output will always contain the same number of lines as File 1?

To be more specific, I have two files with four columns:

File 1:

```
1    800     800     0.51

2    801     801     0.01

3    802     802     0.01

4    803     803     0.23
```

---

File 2:

```
1    800     800     0.55

2    801     801     0.09

3    802     802     0.88

4    803     804     0.24
```

---

This is what I am using now:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3];next}($1,$2,$3) in a{print $4}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

---

This generates the following output:

```
0.55

0.09

0.88
```

---

However, I want to get this:

```
0.55

0.09

0.88

Not Found
```

---

Could you please help?
Sorry if this is presented in a confusing manner; I have little experience with awk and am confused myself.

---

In a separate issue, I want to  end up having a file that has the data from File 2 added on to File1, like so:

```
1 800 800 0.51 0.55

2 801 801 0.01 0.09

3 802 802 0.01 0.88

4 803 803 0.23 Not Found
```

I was going to generate the file as before (lets call it file2-matches.txt), then use the paste command:

paste -d"\t" file1.txt file2-matches.txt > output.txt

But considering I have to do this matching for over 100 files, is there any more efficient way to do this that you can suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `else` clause:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3];next} {if (($1,$2,$3) in a) {print $4} else {print "not found"}}' f1 f2
0.55
0.09
0.88
not found
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to get that to work but couldn't get the syntax right.

Comment: I should perhaps post this as a separate question, but do you happen to know if there is a way to make it so that any extra lines from file2 that are not in file1 are still added after the rest, at the end? Including the file2 columns 1 2 3 ?? Thanks so much

Comment: Separate question, yes

Comment: You can simplify further `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3];next}(($1,$2,$3) in a){print $4;next}{print "not found"} ' f1 f2`